# Unity C# - run php and read html result

Tags: php, unity-game-engine

I make a request from Unity (I tried both, with the obsolete WWW and with UnityWebRequest.Get(url);)
I have no return text.

I think, my code is correct:

```
// (in a coroutine)
UnityWebRequest hs_get = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
yield return hs_get.SendWebRequest();
mytext = hs_get.downloadHandler.text;
```

"mytext" is always empty.But if I run the URL from a browser, **the php page works** and gives me the text that I need.
Is it possible that my php server does not accept requests from Unity for some reason?

PHP Version 5.4.16

[EDIT]

```
    IEnumerator GetWebData()
{
    string url = "https://www.artistic-minds.it/test1.html";
    UnityWebRequest hs_get = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);

    yield return hs_get.SendWebRequest();

   //  while (!hs_get.isDone && string.IsNullOrEmpty(hs_get.error))
   //  {
   //     yield return null;
   //  }

    //yield return hs_get;

   // string pageText = Regex.Replace(hs_get.downloadHandler.text, "<.*?>", String.Empty);

    string pageText = hs_get.downloadHandler.text;

    print("<color=#FFFF00>WorldLeader request URL</color> " + url);
    print("<color=#FFFF00>Return Text</color> " + pageText);


    if (hs_get.error != null )
    {
        print("<color=#FF5500>There was an error getting the high score -</color> " + hs_get.error);
    }
    else
    {
        PrintOnText(pageText.Trim());
    }
}
```

Some lines are commented, I also tested that way.
[image: shot]

Comment: if you are being returned the php code not the results of it, what do you see if you pull up the url in your browser, it should be the same

Comment: In fact, it should be the same. But it is not, any URL I put. 
I also did tests with test pages, like "google.com". And it works.

Comment: that seems incredibly odd, as the content is generated at the webserver it shouldnt disern between unity and a browser,

Comment: Could you add your php code?

Comment: It doesn't depend on PHP, I also tried with a simple html page (https://www.artistic-minds.it/test1.html). If it's on my server it doesn't work.

Comment: debug a Little more your webrequest result. Use conditions in your hs_get isDone, isHttpError and isNetworkError to check.

Comment: I edit the Question with full coroutine function code.
Can anyone test it? With the link to my test page, on my host. I think it depends on that because, as mentioned, on a link like "google.com" it works as it should.